# Magento2 Documentation Suggestions or Issue Raising

Tags: magento2, documentation

Is there any way to make `Suggestions or Raise Issues` regarding the official Magento 2 docs?

If so where and how is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess [here](https://github.com/magento/devdocs).

Taken from [this page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/contributor-guide/contributing.html#report).